# Copy file from apphomepath to download folder in codenameone

Tags: android, codenameone

i am working at a codenameone app. i like to make gpx files the app and copy those files to the download folder on my phone. So that i can later use this files. I didn't find a good solution in stackoverflow or in the codenameone developper guide. The gpx file is created in the webview with javascript

i tried to this
(a) with javascript My code works well on the desktop but not on the phone.
(b) native code. i used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory but that is deprecated with api 29.

Does somebody has a solution. The easiest way would be with javascript.

My code in javascript is

```
async function getsaveFile(content, filenm) {
// create a new handle
const opts = {

    types: [
        {
          
            description: "Text file",
            accept: { "text/plain": [".txt"] },
        },
    ],
};


const newHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(opts);

// create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to
const writableStream = await newHandle.createWritable();
let blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });
// write our file
await writableStream.write(blob);

// close the file and write the contents to disk.
await writableStream.close();
```

}

Comment: What's the build error? You can send the error log to the chat on the website since the error is sometimes hard to read.

Comment: @shai Among the error was Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory but that is deprecated with api 29. I updated the question

Comment: Deprecated != removed. The error is probably different but still we were forced to update to API 33. JavaScript can't write to the download directory on Android either. API 33 changed a lot on Android and we're working on improving that experience. This is discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/12kxe2x/writing_to_android_shared_storage/).